# Where is the source code for templates created in the Customize-Quotes-Templates section located?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to locate the source code used to create templates found in the Setup-Build-Customize-Quotes-Templates section.  I have the need to append additional information to a template but there is no way to do this using clicks.  Thanks in advance for everyone's feedback.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to customise the templates using clicks, or are you saying that the you are unable to achieve your requirement by configuring the template and hence looking to update to source code. If it is the latter, then it is not possible

Comment: I managed to customize the template with clicks but needed to added additional material to make it a multi-page document hence requiring the source code.  It looks like this is not possible using the native template so I'll need to explore VisualForce or other app options.  Thanks for your help Mahat Hussein.

Comment: No worries - you might want to update your question to specify your requirements, somebody might have a workaround.....in terms of apps on the appexchange I would recommend DrawLoop used that multiple times and it is very easy to configure. (It is paid thou)

Comment: I found a way to customize the template without using the source code.  I simply created a new section and inserted a text/image field.  From there, I copied the content from the document that I wanted to append to the template.  So far it is working out with a few minor spacing modifications.  Thanks again for your feedback Mahat.